# Wtrite two buffers in MIPS files

Tags: assembly, mips

```
 # open a file
 li $v0, 13         # open file code
 la $a0, fileOut    # file name to open
 li $a1, 1          # flag for read only 0 = read; 1 write/create; 9 write/create/append
 li $a2, 0          # flag for ignore
 syscall            # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0) 

 move $s6, $v0      # file descriptor

 # write file
 li $v0, 15
 move $a0, $s6   # move fd
 la $a1, bigger_word
 li $a2, 1024
 la $a3, smaller_word
 li $t4, 1024
 syscall
```

How can I write two buffers in a file at the same time? When I run this piece of code only one buffer is written.

Comment: _"at the same time"_ You can't (unless the second buffer directly follows the first one in memory). You'll have two use system call 15 twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @[Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1524450/michael) suggestion here is the final code. It works.

```
 # write file first address
 li $v0, 15
 move $a0, $s6   # move fd
 la $a1, smaller_word
 li $a2, 1024
 syscall

 # write file break line
 li $v0, 15
 move $a0, $s6   # move fd
 la $a1, endLine
 li $a2, 4
 syscall

 # write file second address
 li $v0, 15
 move $a0, $s6   # move fd
 la $a1, bigger_word
 li $a2, 1024
 syscall
```